# what is the best way to perform multiple inserts with tedious nodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, sql-server, node-modules, tedious

what is the best way to open and close connections when multiple inserts are made, through a stored procedure with tedious

```
        try {
  let conn = await Con.create();
            for (let i = 0; i < parameters.length; i++) {
                await conn.queryExec("PRO_insertValuesClients", parameters[i]);
            }
         
            conn.end();
```

the problem in this way that sometimes i get the error, I don't understand what is causing the error

```
Failed to connect to 10.78.56.21:1433 - connect EADDRINUSE 10.78.56.21:1433
```

I wanted to try this way, but I don't know if it is the best or if there is another way, if you can advise me
Thank you

```
 try {
            for (let i = 0; i < parameters.length; i++) {
let conn = await Con.create();
                await conn.queryExec("PRO_insertValuesClients", parameters[i]);
    conn.end();
            }
```

Comment: I would suggest a single insert to insert all the rows at once. But if you stick with looping and inserting over and over you should create the connection and then close it outside of the loop.

Comment: How can I  insert all the rows at once.?

Comment: You could modify your procedure to receive a table valued parameter and pass the whole collection.